# form to database connection

Tags: php, database

I have a form that is not working correctly with the database. Please help
I used a newsletter.php code that I already had and edited the login information to fit this clients needs. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="newsletter.php">
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
                    <div class="6u"><input type="text" class="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row half">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="12u">
                        <ul class="actions">
                            <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" /></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

newsletter.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define('DB_NAME', 'Newsletter');
define('DB_USER', '*****');
define('DB_PASSWORD','******');
define('DB_HOST','50.62.209.154:3306');

$link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connnect to the database' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use' . DB_NAME . ':' . mysql_error());
}

echo 'Connected Successfuly';

$value = $_POST['name,email,message']; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (name, email, message) VALUES ('$value')"; 
echo "value=$value sql=$sql";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: This is just wrong `$value = $_POST['name,email,message'];` use seperate POST variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$value = '"'.$_POST['name'].'","'.$_POST['email'].'","'.$_POST'message'].'"';
```

Although I would recommend looking into using MySQIi as the MySQL library is deprecated with newer versions of PHP, as well as looking into prepared statements and data sanitization to prevent against SQL injections.

**EDIT**

You should also at the very least use mysql_real_escape_string() around each POST variable to prevent people form typing in a single quote (or double quote depending on which you wrap your code with) and it causing an issue.

Such as:

```
$value = '"'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']).'","'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST'message']).'"';
```

**EDIT WITH INFO FROM COMMENTS**

Like mentioned by Charlotte, you really should also get into using PDO. One of the guides I enjoyed following about it while trying to learn it was: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

But you may want to ask Charlotte if she has any other resources as she is much more familiar with PDO than I am.

Comment: He should rather start with PDO than MySQLi. PDO has a better integration of Prepared Statements.

Comment: Very true, I myself am lacking in the PDO department, so I often forget about it. Thanks for the added info!

Comment: 3 columns, 1 value? Not to mention a typo `$avlue`

Comment: @Fred thanks for the typo catch! And yes, I know best practice would be to not include all of those together. For sake of simplicity, I did give up some of the best practices, which I shouldn't have done, but thanks again for noticing the typo! :)